# Create a Dynamic Grid of Animated Buttons in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, button, grid

I'm new to Flash and intermediate in HTML/CSS. I would like to create a grid of buttons that when you hover over them, they change color and show a linkable caption/tooltip on hover. I would also like this to be dynamic as possible as I will need a grid of 2000+ buttons/squares that may have to be updated from time to time.

[Here is an example created with HTML/CSS and some JS](http://jsfiddle.net/xGGr8/49/)

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function () {



    // This will automatically grab the 'title' attribute and replace
    // the regular browser tooltips for all <a> elements with a title attribute!
    $('a[title]').qtip();

});
});//]]>
```

I need to know the best way to build this in flash, and would really appreciate a barebones breakdown of the code/AS. I am somewhat new to flash and this is just way above my head.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want grid of small bitmaps/shapes on stage. I would recommend bitmaps since they work better when you want to transform something - but if the grid will be standing still, then you can use Sprite filled with color. Below you can find a snippet complete example. You can compile it using mxmlc compiler or using Flash Develop||FDT, or connecting this file as a *document class* in Flash IDE.

It's the most efficient way I can imagine. We have only one Sprite and we color some parts of it depending on where our mouse is. Hope this helps.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author 
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var color:int = 0xf2f2f2;
        private var color1:int = 0xff000;//colors definition
        private var size:int = 12;//size of our square
        private var container:Sprite;//container definition
        private var rows:int = 48;//number of rows
        private var margin:int = 2;//margin on each side
        private var count:int = 2000;//number of elements
        private var totalspace:int = size + margin;
        private var currentPoint:Point = new Point();
        private var lastPoint:Point = null;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            container = new Sprite();//define squares container;
            container.graphics.beginFill(color);//define fill color;

            var posX:int;
            var posY:int;

            for ( var i:int = 0; i < count; i++) {
                posX = int(i % rows) * totalspace;//calculate x axis position based on modulo
                posY = int(i / rows) * totalspace;//calculate y axis position
                container.graphics.drawRect( posX, posY, size, size );//call drawRect method on graphics object.
            }

            addChild(container);//add container to stage - meaning it will be visible, because flash is rendering it.
            container.buttonMode = true;//set mouse to button mode
            container.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMM );
            container.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onMO );
            //add eventListener for mouse move - so each time you move a mouse over container object it will trigger an event.
        }

        private function onMO(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            currentPoint = null;
        }

        private function onMM(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if ( lastPoint == currentPoint ) {
                //if moouse is on the same square exit this function
                return;
            }
            //calculate x and y position of square we need to color
            currentPoint = new Point( int( container.mouseX/totalspace ) * totalspace, int(container.mouseY/totalspace) * totalspace );
            container.graphics.beginFill( color1 );
            container.graphics.drawRect( currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, size, size );

            if ( lastPoint ) {
                //if last point is present, make it grey, as for roll out
                container.graphics.beginFill( color );
                container.graphics.drawRect( lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, size, size );
            }

            lastPoint = currentPoint;
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Szczcups! Now I am stuck on how to turn this code into a working .swf file ;/ lol. Nooobie here, much appreciated!

Comment: Easiest things to do would be: 

1. Download FlashDevelop and create AS3 project. Then in src folder paste code I wrote above. Hit ctrl+enter and enjoy :)
2. Save above code as Main.as file and copy it to the folder with sample as3 fla file. Then in flash IDE in file properties set Main.as as a document class - then hit ctrl+enter and enjoy.

Comment: I'm having problems with FlashDevelop on my PC, and will need to spend more time on installing it later.

For now - and sorry to flip the 'script' - but I have managed to create a grid in AS3 in Flash CS6:

<code>